# Map function will not render in nextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to get familiar with NextJS so I am building a simple blog. The data is passed thru props and can be console logged inside of the map function, but for some reason will not display any HTML in a browser. no errors to be shown. Prettier in VScode also had to be turned off bc it was adding ";" every time I would save this map function

```
 <div>
        {post.map((post) => {
          {console.log(post.description + "here")}
          <h1>post</h1>
          
        })}
 </div>
```

console log will show up in the console but the h1 does render to screen.

Does anybody have some advice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, you need to check `post.map((post) => (...)`. They're having the same variable `post` from inner to outer. It should be `posts.map((post) => (...))` (with `posts` for the loop)

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function also expects a return value, but you haven't returned any value

```
 <div>
        {posts.map((post) => {
          return <h1>post</h1>
        })}
 </div>
```

The shorter version (without brackets)

```
 <div>
   {posts.map((post) => <h1>post</h1>)}
 </div>
```

I'd suggest you have [`key`](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) in `map` results too that would help React recognize your unique elements in `posts` for re-rendering

```
 <div>
   {posts.map((post) => <h1 key={post.id}>post</h1>)} //`post.id` is a unique value
 </div>
```

Comment: You're welcome!~ By the way, could you mark the answer done too? That would help other people facing a similar problem like yours :D @AdamKuemmel

Answer (score 1):

```js
 <div>
        {post.map((post) => (
          {console.log(post.description + "here")}
          <h1>post</h1>
          
        ))}
 </div>
```

The map function was not not returning anything . so added the parenthesis or you can use return() and paste the console section